# dynamic creation of array based on previous value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say I have a data frame as follows:

```
   BID diff
 1   1 NA
 2   1 0.0
 3   1 0.0
 4   1 -0.5
 5   1 0.0
 6   1 0.0
 7   1 0.0
 8   1 0.5
 9   1 0.0
10   1 0.0
11   2 NA
12   2 0.0
13   2 0.0
14   2 0.0
15   2 -0.5
16   2 0.0
17   2 0.0
18   2 0.0
19   2 0.0
20   3 NA
21   3 0.5
22   3 0.0
23   3 -0.5
24   3 0.5
```

What I would like to do is, for each `BID`, create a new variable `neg` that is equal to 0 before a negative `diff` value and equal to 1 after a negative `diff` value. However it should stop when `diff` changes again. E.g.

```
   BID diff neg
 1   1 NA   0
 2   1 0.0  0
 3   1 0.0  0
 4   1 -0.5 NA
 5   1 0.0  1
 6   1 0.0  1
 7   1 0.0  1
 8   1 0.5  NA
 9   1 0.0  NA
10   1 0.0  NA
11   2 NA   0
12   2 0.0  0
13   2 0.0  0
14   2 0.0  0
15   2 -0.5 NA
16   2 0.0  1
17   2 0.0  1
18   2 0.0  1
19   2 0.0  1
20   3 NA   NA
21   3 0.5  NA
22   3 0.0  0
23   3 -0.5 NA
24   3 0.5  NA
```

I tried approaching the running '1's with `dplyr` as follows:

```
data <- data %>% 
  group_by(BID) %>% 
  mutate(neg = 
         as.numeric(
             ifelse(lag(diff) == -0.5, 1,
                    ifelse(((lag(neg) == 1) & (diff == 0.0)),
                                        lag(neg), 0))))
```

I guess it's somewhat obvious now that this only works if two or fewer 1's are needed following a -0.5 in `diff`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I am open to other methods besides `dplyr`. The data itself is a time series and `diff` is the difference between another variable's current and lagged value for each BID. Let me know if any other information may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most efficient way to do it, but here you go:

```
df <- read.table(text = '   BID diff
                 1   1 NA
                 2   1 0.0
                 3   1 0.0
                 4   1 -0.5
                 5   1 0.0
                 6   1 0.0
                 7   1 0.0
                 8   1 0.5
                 9   1 0.0
                 10   1 0.0
                 11   2 NA
                 12   2 0.0
                 13   2 0.0
                 14   2 0.0
                 15   2 -0.5
                 16   2 0.0
                 17   2 0.0
                 18   2 0.0
                 19   2 0.0
                 20   3 NA
                 21   3 0.5
                 22   3 0.0
                 23   3 -0.5
                 24   3 0.5', header = FALSE)

df[is.na(df)] <- 0
df$neg <- 0

for (i in 1:length(df$diff)) {
  flag <- ifelse(df$diff[i] < 0, 1, 0)
  if (flag == 1) {
    for (j in i:length(df$diff)) {
      if (df$diff[j] > 0) {
        flag <- 0
        break
      } else {
        df$neg[j] <- 1
      }
    }
  }
}

df$neg[df$diff < 0] <- 0
df
##    BID diff neg
## 1    1  0.0   0
## 2    1  0.0   0
## 3    1  0.0   0
## 4    1 -0.5   0
## 5    1  0.0   1
## 6    1  0.0   1
## 7    1  0.0   1
## 8    1  0.5   0
## 9    1  0.0   0
## 10   1  0.0   0
## 11   2  0.0   0
## 12   2  0.0   0
## 13   2  0.0   0
## 14   2  0.0   0
## 15   2 -0.5   0
## 16   2  0.0   1
## 17   2  0.0   1
## 18   2  0.0   1
## 19   2  0.0   1
## 20   3  0.0   1
## 21   3  0.5   0
## 22   3  0.0   0
## 23   3 -0.5   0
## 24   3  0.5   0
```

What's happening is: everytime it finds a negative number in `diff`, it sets a flag, and changes all the following values to 1, till it finds a positive number.

Comment: I don't think this is the desired output. There should be `NAs` here somewhere too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it is closer than what I was getting. Unfortunately David is correct in that it is not the desired output. More than anything, because it ignores the groups. For instance, `df$neg[20]` should certainly not be 1. I'm trying to work out a functional solution using data.table, but it will definitely be inefficient.